# _OSByteOrder.h:49:1: error: function definition is not allowed here

Tags: c, xcode7-beta5

I am including dyld.h to provide the function _NSGetExecutablePath()
which will give the path to the executable for OS X 10.10.

But when including dyld.h in a C compile,  I get the following error:

/usr/include/libkern/i386/_OSByteOrder.h:49:1: error: function definition is not allowed here.

The messages before the above are:
In file included from testCode.c:11:
In file included from /usr/include/mach-o/dyld.h:31: 
In file included from /usr/include/mach-o/loader.h:48: In file included from /usr/include/architecture/byte_order.h:38

It appears that  dyld.h starts a train of includes that ends with an error.
Does anyone know the requirements for using dyld.h or _NSGetExecutablePath()?

Comment: The messages before the above are:
 In file included from testCode.c:11:

In file included from /usr/include/mach-o/dyld.h:31:

In file included from /usr/include/mach-o/loader.h:48:

In file included from /usr/include/architecture/byte_order.h:38:

Comment: Please edit your original question, what you've added to the comment is cut off.

Comment: Show the code around the error - it sounds like a simple syntax error in your source, such as wrapping the #include in the main.

Comment: Petesh is correct. I found the syntax error exactly as he suspected. Thank you.